# Listview NullPointerException inside onCreateDialogView

Tags: android, android-dialog

Im trying to create a dialog, it works except when I try and add this ListView part

```
 protected View onCreateDialogView() {  
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();
    View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_content_view, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Log.i("DIALOG", lv.toString()); ---- **RIGHT HERE IT BREAKS at com.example.tvrplayer.ChannelsDialogPreference.onCreateDialogView(ChannelsDialogPreference.java:56)**
    return vw;
 }
```

If I remove that Listview bit, It works and shows the empty Dialog.

**channel_content_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/channels_list"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal">      

</LinearLayout>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at com.example.tvrplayer.ChannelsDialogPreference.onCreateDialogView(ChannelsDialogPreference.java:56)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:285)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:264)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:939)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:202)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1173)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2701)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3453)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-28 13:37:15.768: E/AndroidRuntime(24732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i can't find any listview defined in channel_content_view.xml.. that may b possible reason for null pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I see that to. Im adding it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout doesn't have any ListView.

Add one into your LinearLayout, give it an ID and use that to find the ListView lv

Comment: Oh that makes sence, let me try that

Comment: Would it be ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list); if I made a listview inside LinearLayout with id list ?

Comment: use R.id.your_given_id , so you're sure you're getting the correct list. In ListActivitys you can use the Android.r... one but then you still have to give that to the ListView as Id.